# How to use Collective in laravel5.3

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I've upgraded From L4.2 to L5.3.20 and I've tried to use with Collective-laravel FormFacades and HTMLFacade with below code but I got the errors result in my drop down. how should I correct it

```
{{ Form::select('employeeID', $employees,null,['class' => 'form-control input-xlarge select2me','data-placeholder'=>'Select Employee...']) }}


'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Result:

```
{"id":25,"employeeID":"asdfasdfasdf","fullName":"Sdfas","email":"ddd@yahoo.com","gender":"female","fatherName":"Dfasdfasdf","mobileNumber":"3452345","date_of_birth":"2016-10-11","designation":1,"joiningDate":"2016-10-31","profileImage":"Sdfas_asdfasdfasdf.png","localAddress":"234523","permanentAddress":"452345","status":null,"last_login":null,"remember_token":null,"exit_date":null,"created_at":"2016-10-27 02:21:56","updated_at":"2016-10-27 02:21:56"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give well formatted data to `select`. Laravel has `pluck()` method which is perfect for this job:

```
$employees = Employee::pluck('employeeID', 'id');
```